# How does Silvery Barbs interact with other "reroll" effects?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, feats, advantage-and-disadvantage

[This other question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/193484/how-does-the-silvery-barbs-spell-interact-with-the-enemy-having-advantage) discusses how *silvery barbs* interacts with advantage and disadvantage. But there are some effects that let someone reroll a d20 without using the advantage/disadvantage mechanic, such as the Lucky feat or legendary resistances.

How does *silvery barbs* interact with these? For example, can I use Lucky to reroll a failure caused by *silvery barbs*, or use *silvery barbs* to force an enemy to reroll again after they use a legendary resistance to succeed? And does this change at all if the original roll had advantage or disadvantage?

Comment: I think we’ve got a duplicate here. Check the linked question and let us know if they answers your question. *It should*, but maybe I’m missing something.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov To me there's a fundamental difference: all the features mentioned in that question are used by the same person (the one who made the roll), while _silvery barbs_ is imposed by someone else. This means it now matters when in the process the reaction for _silvery barbs_ triggers: the caster doesn't necessarily get to choose whether they use it before or after something else (to my read).

Comment: Hmm, that is a good point. You’ve sold it to me.

Answer (score 5):

### Legendary Resistance

> If the lich fails a saving throw, it can choose to succeed instead.

*Silvery Barbs* will force the creature to reroll and take the lowest. If that's a failure, it can choose to succeed.

### Lucky

*Silvery Barbs* beats Lucky because the Lucky feat requires you to use it "before the outcome is determined", while *Silvery Barbs* happens when that roll succeeds i.e. *after* the outcome is determined.

### Halfling Luck

This works as normal, if you roll a 1, you reroll once even if that roll was caused by *Silvery Barbs*. You still take the lowest.

### Advantage/Disadvantage

This is addressed in [How does the silvery barbs spell interact with the enemy having advantage?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/193484/how-does-the-silvery-barbs-spell-interact-with-the-enemy-having-advantage) None of the above make any difference to this.

Comment: The part about Legendary Resistance now has been officially published as part of the errata overview: https://dnd.wizards.com/dndstudioblog/sage-advice-book-updates